# Is it possible to use Wifi and Bluetooth at the same time on a RPi 3B+?

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, pi-3b+

I need to connect to WiFi and Bluetooth at the same time using an RPi 3B+. Is it possible or will one connection drop out or be very substandard while using the other?

Comment: Yes, it is posssible without any problen,

Comment: Thanks, because I read that it was not so perhaps that was an earlier version. I am asking because many chips that do both bluetooth and WiFi cannot do them simultaneously but are just capable of doing both but only one or the other at a time. Do you know if the RPi 3B+ able to do this because of the chip firmware or are they able to do this because they have added something external to the chip?

Comment: I didn't went so deep. But I use it every day for testing Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth LE features. RPi connected to my network through WiFi. Both (Bluetooth and WiFi) works perfect (especially because I use VNC to control Raspberry).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the RPi3B+ works fine with wifi and Bluetooth together. In fact, I am currently using a Rii wifi mini-keyboard, a Logitech wifi mouse and a iRulu Bluetooth mini-keyboard on my RPi3B+, simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Both are independent functions of your Raspberry Pi, both can work at the same time.

Comment: The question has exactly the same answer half a year before.